# .addClass - Object Gold has no method 'addClass'

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm having a little problem. I keep getting the following error when trying to change a style / add a style:

```
Object Gold has no method 'addClass'
```

This is the code in my .js file:

```
 function GetSelectedCoverLevel(id) {


        SelectedLevel = $(id).attr('id');
        SelectedLevel.addClass("selectedboo");

 }
```

And this is my HTML file:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GetSelectedCoverLevel(this);" id="Gold"  class="btn green">
```

It's probably something simple but I can't see it at the moment.

Comment: ugh obtrusive JavaScript...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are passing the dom element reference to `GetSelectedCoverLevel`, you need to get the jQuery wrapper for this element which provides access to jQuery utility methods.

In your case you are assigning the `id` attribute of the element to `SelectedLevel` which is a string and does no have the method `addClass`

```
var SelectedLevel = $(id).addClass("selectedboo");
```

Comment: Or in fact just `$(id).addClass('selectedboo')`.

Comment: @lonesomeday yes, I went with what the OP already had, the variable might be used somewhere else also

Comment: function GetSelectedCoverLevel(id) {


        SelectedLevel = $(id).attr('id');
       $('#'+SelectedLevel).addClass("selectedboo");

 }, this should work

Comment: He could also write it as `SelectedLevel = $(id).addClass("selectedboo");`  ..OR.. `SelectedLevel = $(id).addClass("selectedboo").attr('id');`

Comment: jQuery chaining is awesome, course my second example would only return the ID, but i didn't really read enough to know if he'd want the ID or the Element Object after ...